# How to detect MIME-type from PSR-7 UploadedFileInterface

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types, psr-7

I have a simple controller that handles image uploads. Before saving the image/file to its final destination i would like to validate the mimeType of that file.

My controller uses `Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface` and calls `getUploadedFiles()` to get the uploaded files as instances of `Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface`.

On an instance of that interface I can now call `getClientMediaType()` to get the mime type.

My problem is that the documentation explicitly states not to trust that value! 
Because of that i would like to detect the mimeType with `mime_content_type()` but I cant get the actual filename from that interface.

I see two options:

- i could just use $_FILES and call mime_content_type($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])
- i could move the file and to a place that i know and then call mime_content_type() but that would defeat the purpose of NOT moving the file before validation

Here is a abbreviated version of my controller:

```php
    public function handleUpload(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {
        $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
        /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $files[0];

        $fileType = $uploadedFile->getClientMediaType(); // This need to be replaced !
        if (!in_array($fileType, self::VALID_IMAGE_MIME_TYPE)) {
            // return error
        }

        // do stuff
    }
```

Is there a method i'm not seeing on how to get the tmp_name from the UploadedFileInterface? Is there another best practise to do this kind of validation? It seems a very obvious problem, so i guess i'm missing something basic.

Comment: Well, by looking at the interface I don't see any direct possibility. However I see two options: You can call getStream(), save it somewhere and then check it and move it to target location if the mime type is as desired. Second option is to check if the implementation doesn't expose the tmp path, but you would then have to depend on the implementation and not the interface. So if you want to use only the interface, saving the stream seems like an only option to me.

Comment: thanks @Rikudou_Sennin that idea with the stream got me to a solution:
get the stream, get the metaData for that stream and this includes the tmp_name that i can then pass to the `mime_content_type()`

`$stream = $uploadedFile->getStream();`

`$tmpFilename = $stream->getMetadata("uri");`

`$fileType = mime_content_type($tmpFilename);`

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.